# Seeder is not a constructor mongoose-data-seed nextJs

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, next.js, seed

I have website using nextjs and mongoose.

for having seed data i used mongoose-data-seed plugin

now i get error when run command md-seed run

Error is:
Seeding Results:
× AboutSeeder
TypeError: Seeder is not a constructor

md-seed-config.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const {AboutSeeder} = require("./seeders/about.seeder")
const mongoURL = process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb+srv://***:**@***.3sxb0yu.mongodb.net/***?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

 const seedersList = {
  AboutSeeder
};

 const connect = async () =>
  await mongoose.connect(mongoURL, { useNewUrlParser: true });

 const dropdb = async () => mongoose.connection.db.dropDatabase();

 module.exports = {seedersList, connect,dropdb}
```

seeders/about.seeder.js

```
const { Seeder } =   require('mongoose-data-seed');
const { LandingAboutModel } =   require('../models/landingaboutModel');


const data = [{
  pretitle: "pretitle",
  title: "title",
  description: "description."
}];

class AboutSeeder extends Seeder {

  async shouldRun() {
    return LandingAboutModel.countDocuments().exec().then(count => count === 0);
  }

  async run() {
    return LandingAboutModel.create(data);
  }
}

module.export = {AboutSeeder};
```

models/landingaboutModel.js

```
const { Model, models, model } =  require("mongoose");
const { Document, Schema } =  require("mongoose");


const landingSchema = new Schema({
    pretitle: {
        type:String,
        required: true,
        trim:true,
        minlength: 3
    },
    title: {
        type:String,
        required: true,
        trim:true,
        minlength: 3
    },
    description:{type:String,
        required: true,
        trim:true,
        minlength: 20},
    
})


const LandingAboutModel = models.Feedback || model("landingabout", landingSchema)

module.export =  {LandingAboutModel}
```

i add some babel configuration in package.json but problem did not solved.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "***",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "start": "next start",
    "build": "next build",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.4",
    "eslint": "8.44.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.9",
    "mongoose": "^7.4.3",
    "mongoose-data-seed": "^2.1.6",
  },
  "mdSeed": {
    "seedersFolder": "./seeders"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.11",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
  }
}
```